# Advanced Calc II question- Riemann integration

Tags: calculus

Prove that the only function $f:\Bbb R\rightarrow\Bbb R$ such that $f'=f$ and $f(0)=1$ is given by $f(x)=e^x$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Let $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$. Using the Product Rule, show that $g'(x)=0$ (identically).

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be any function with those properties, then $f'/f \equiv1$ and integrating:
$$ \int_0^x \frac{f'(u)}{f(u)} \; du = \int_0^x1=x $$
make the change of variable $s=f(u)$ and use that $\int 1/s ds = \ln(s)$. You then have
$$ \int_{f(0)}^{f(x)} \frac{1}{s} \; ds = \ln(s)|_1^{f(x)}=x$$
since $\ln(1)=0$ this implies that
$$ \ln(f(x))=x$$ 
and therefore
$$ f(x) = e^x.$$
You can conclude that $e^x$ is the only function with the desired properties.